# Using MultipleFileUpload via TransferManager of AWS Java SDK is throwing exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

That's the exception I am receiving on calling **waitForCompletion()** of MultipleFileUpload

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: org/apache/http/conn/ManagedHttpClientConnection
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.unwrapExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:277)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.rethrowExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:261)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.waitForCompletion(AbstractTransfer.java:103)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.MultipleFileUploadImpl.waitForCompletion(MultipleFileUploadImpl.java:77)
at com.common.S3Uploader.upload(S3Uploader.java:49)
at com.common.S3Uploader.main(S3Uploader.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ManagedHttpClientConnection
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:837)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3674)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1437)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Maven for building with AWS-SDK version 1.10.59
Loading AWS credentials from ProfileCredentialsProvider.

Comment: you need add dependency on apache http client in your pom

Comment: Thanks @MaximS.Ivanov for help. Had to add two dependencies: _apache-http-client_ and _apache-http-core_.